# Control displays in go json structure

Tags: json, go

I am working on a golang nested structure and want to control which substructures to display in JSON.

Here is an example. if I want to display only treeid and name field from Citrus, I am trying below notation, but it is still printing the entire Citrus structure. I don't want the third structure variable under Citrus. How do I control it?

```
type trees struct {
     Id    int
     CitrusTree *Citrus `json:"name,treeid,omitempty"`
     VegTree  *Veg
}
type Citrus struct {
     treeid  int
     name string
     substuct *someStruct
}
```

Comment: With the code shown, none of the fields of `Citrus` would be marshalled to JSON, because they're all unexported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation on `Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), you exclude a field with `json:"-"`:

```
// Field is ignored by this package.
Field int `json:"-"`
```

Note that the `json` tag works exactly like it says in the docs, which does not include providing a list of fields of a struct field that you want included; that is never mentioned in the docs, and is not how the package works. The tag allows you to specify the name of the field to be used in the JSON, and a couple of flags (e.g. `omitempty`). Passing the name as `-` indicates the field should be excluded. To get the behavior you've described (and correcting the fields of `Citrus` to be exported):

```
type trees struct {
     Id    int
     CitrusTree *Citrus
     VegTree  *Veg
}
type Citrus struct {
     Treeid  int
     Name string
     Substuct *someStruct `json:"-"`
}
```

Or, alternatively, you may be able to only export the fields you want marshalled, depending on whether you need access to those fields from other packages:

```
type trees struct {
     Id    int
     CitrusTree *Citrus
     VegTree  *Veg
}
type Citrus struct {
     Treeid  int
     Name string
     substuct *someStruct
}
```

Since unexported fields cannot be martialed, they will be excluded from the JSON output.

Comment: yes, `json:"-"` worked! thanks.  If I want to omit the fields in Citrus structure if they are empty, I added 'omitempty tag'. But I still see the display as {}. Is it possible to avoid printing the structure all together and print other fields from 'trees' struct. This is only if the values 'Treeid' and 'Name' are empty and omitted.

Comment: No. A `*Citrus` with `omitempty` will only be omitted if its value is `nil`.

Comment: So even with these changes in the Citrus structure, i think I see {} in the json output for tree structure. Is it because the structure is empty but not nil? 
type Citrus struct {
     Treeid  int `json:"treeid,omitempty""`
     Name string `json:"name,omitempty""`
     substuct *someStruct 'json:"-"'

Comment: Yes.  A `*Citrus` with `omitempty` will only be omitted if its value is `nil`.